# Looping through JSON object with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift

I make a request to an API to GET data from from the code below:

```
 func loadTenantData()
{
    let methods = Methods()

    methods.getApiData(completion: { 

        print(methods.getJSON())
        for item in methods.getJSON()[0]
        {
            print(item)
        }

    }, fullUrl: BackupChecker().getAllTenants())
}
```

The print(methods.getJSON()) line prints:

```
[{"TenantID":1,"Tenant1":"RAC"},{"TenantID":2,"Tenant1":"VictorMillwell"},{"TenantID":3,"Tenant1":"Comfort"},{"TenantID":4,"Tenant1":"Greenlight"},{"TenantID":5,"Tenant1":"Kinetic"}]
```

For some reason this doesn't iterate through the methods.getJSON which returns the JSON, does anyone know why?

Comment: Could it be because the print method you use above is *outside* of the iteration? Tell us what you want to achieve or what value from the JSON you want to retrieve?

Comment: My two cents: abandon SwiftyJSON and start learning the Decodable / Encodable JSON protocols introduced in Swift 4. They allow you to use generics and error handling way better than SwiftyJSON. Take it from a guy who's used the later for over a year and vouched for it constantly.

Answer (score 0):

You're only accessing the first index - that's why it won't iterate. Remove [0] after .getJSON()

```
for item in methods.getJSON()[0] // <-- Remove [0] to loop through the rest
{
    print(item)
}
```